# The meromorphic continuation of Selberg-like integrals in the symmetric case

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, mp.mathematical-physics

**Introduction.**
In connection with the question (1) (link below), I've been trying to understand the meromorphic continuation in $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ of the Selberg-like integral $$ S_N(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) = \int_{\Delta_N} p(x_1,\ldots,x_N) \Big[\prod_{n=1}^N x_n^\alpha (1-x_n)^\beta\Big]\prod_{1\leq m<n\leq N} (x_n-x_m)^{2\gamma} \,\mathrm{d} x_N\cdots \mathrm{d}x_1, \tag{$*$}$$
where $\Delta_N=\{0<x_1<\cdots<x_N<1\}$ and $p\in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_N]$, this being defined initially for $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ such that the integrand above is absolutely integrable.
It seems to be an easy corollary of a result of Aomoto (2) and Kanie-Tsuchiya (3) (which involves a generalization of the Pochhammer regularization of the Euler Beta function) that, for some $p$-dependent entire function $J_N(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) : \mathbb{C}^3\to \mathbb{C}$,
$$
S_N(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) = \Big[  \prod_{j=0}^{N-1} s((j+1)(\alpha+j\gamma)) s((j+1)(\beta+j\gamma)) s((j+1)(j+2)\gamma)^{N-j-1} \Big]^{-1} J_N(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)
\tag{$**$}
$$
for all $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ such that the original integral ($*$) makes sense. Here $s(t)=\sin(\pi t)$. In particular, $S_N$ can be "meromorphically continued" in $\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in \mathbb{C}^3$, apart from an infinite set of possible poles corresponding to the conditions $j\alpha+j(j-1)\gamma\in \mathbb{Z}$, $j\beta+j(j-1)\gamma\in \mathbb{Z}$, and $j(j+1)\gamma \in \mathbb{Z}$. Some of these poles are obviously removable, for example when the real parts of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are sufficiently large such that the integral ($*$) is well-defined (and actually one has a slightly different cutoff for each trigonometric factor). Roughly speaking -- see (3) for the precise details -- each of the trigonometric factors in ($**$) is related to a face of the associahedron $K_{N+2}$. Such a face is labeled by a proper subset $S$ of consecutive members of $\{0,\ldots,N+1\}$, and the corresponding phase in ($**$) is the exponent of the integrand in ($*$) coming from the regime when all of the members of $\{x_s\}_{s\in S}$ coalesce at a linear rate. (Here $x_0 = 0$ and $x_{N+1}=1$.)

However, I think that for "generic" $p\in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_N]$ (whatever that might mean), all of the potential poles that aren't obviously removable on the right-hand side of ($**$) are genuine poles.

- As an example, consider the case when $N=2$ and $p(x,y)=x^2$. Then,
  *Mathematica* can compute out the meromorphic continuation in $\alpha$, for fixed $\beta$ and $\gamma$. Here is a plot of $|S_N(\alpha,1/2,1/3)|$, now defined by meromorphic continuation, versus $\alpha$:

[image]

Here I have marked the poles associated with the factor $s(\alpha)$ in black and those associated with the factor $s(2\alpha+2\gamma)$, that is $\alpha \in -13/6 - 2^{-1}\mathbb{N}$, in red. Thus, all of the poles that could be there seem to be there.

**Question.**
My question has to do with the case when $p$ is *symmetric*, $p\in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_N]^{S_N}$. Then, it appears to be the case that ($**$) can be sharpened substantially to
$$
S_N(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) = \Big[  \prod_{j=0}^{N-1} s(\alpha+j\gamma) s(\beta+j\gamma) s((j+1)\gamma) \Big]^{-1} \tilde{J}_N(\alpha,\beta,\gamma).
\tag{$*\!*\!*$}
$$
for some entire $\tilde{J}_N$. In other words, many of the apparent poles in ($**$) (which still holds) are actually only removable singularities. Here are two examples which illustrate the phenomenon:

- The classic example is the actual Selberg integral, in which case
  $p=1$ and we have  $$ S_N(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) = \frac{1}{N!}
     \prod_{j=0}^{N-1}
     \frac{\Gamma(1+\alpha+j\gamma)\Gamma(1+\beta+j\gamma)\Gamma(1+(j+1)\gamma)}{\Gamma(2+\alpha+\beta+(n+j-1)\gamma)\Gamma(1+\gamma)}. $$
  For comparison with the example above, the plot of $|S_N(\alpha,1/2,1/3)|$ looks like, where I have marked $\alpha \in -7/6 - 2^{-1}\mathbb{N}$ in red:

[image]

- For $p(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, which is the symmetrization of the first example above, $|S_N(\alpha,1/2,1/3)|$, when plotted against $\alpha$ looks like the following, which is qualitatively similar to the previous example:

[image]

In particular, we can see that half of the poles associated with $s(2\alpha+2\gamma)$ are gone. Only those associated with $s(\alpha+\gamma)$ remain.

How can we conceptually understand this (and prove that this generalizes to all symmetric $p$)? In particular, in the same way that the Aomoto-Kanie-Tsuchiya construction allows us to prove ($**$) by constructing an appropriate element of the twisted homology of of the moduli space $\mathcal{M}_N$ of $N$ distinct labeled elements of the thrice punctured Riemann sphere $\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0,1\}$, can we establish ($*\!*\!*$) by constructing an appropriate element of the twisted homology of the moduli space $\mathcal{M}_N/{S_N}$ of $N$ distinct *unlabeled* elements of the thrice punctured Riemann sphere?

**References:**

1. [Representations of minimal model primary fields in the Coulomb-gas Formalism](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422202/representations-of-minimal-model-primary-fields-in-the-coulomb-gas-formalism).
2. Y. Kanie and A. Tsuchiya, *Fock space representations of Virasoro algebra and intertwining operators*.
3. K. Aomoto, *On the complex Selberg integral*.